# i am getting error in selenese runner java

Tags: selenium

i am new to selenium.

①i downloaded [selenese-runner-java](https://github.com/vmi/selenese-runner-java) from github in my local drive.

②i installed [selenoid](https://aerokube.com/selenoid/latest/).

③i started selenoid and checked its working in my firefox.

④i executed the below command in my local pc powershell

```
java -jar .\selenese-runner.jar --driver firefox  test.html
```

i got the below error

```
[2020-04-30 19:06:58.179 +09:00] [INFO] Start: Selenese Runner 3.30.0
[2020-04-30 19:06:58.776 +09:00] [INFO] No capabilities.
org.openqa.selenium.SessionNotCreatedException: Unable to find a matching set of capabilities
Build info: version: '3.141.59', revision: 'unknown', time: 'unknown'
System info: host: 'LAPTOP-J88KMHEA', ip: '172.31.10.125', os.name: 'Windows 10', os.arch: 'amd64', os.version: '10.0', java.version: '1.8.0_251'
Driver info: driver.version: FirefoxDriver
remote stacktrace:
        at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
        at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(Unknown Source)
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(Unknown Source)
        at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Unknown Source)
        at org.openqa.selenium.remote.W3CHandshakeResponse.lambda$errorHandler$0(W3CHandshakeResponse.java:62)
        at org.openqa.selenium.remote.HandshakeResponse.lambda$getResponseFunction$0(HandshakeResponse.java:30)
        at org.openqa.selenium.remote.ProtocolHandshake.lambda$createSession$0(ProtocolHandshake.java:126)
        at java.util.stream.ReferencePipeline$3$1.accept(Unknown Source)
        at java.util.Spliterators$ArraySpliterator.tryAdvance(Unknown Source)
        at java.util.stream.ReferencePipeline.forEachWithCancel(Unknown Source)
        at java.util.stream.AbstractPipeline.copyIntoWithCancel(Unknown Source)
        at java.util.stream.AbstractPipeline.copyInto(Unknown Source)
        at java.util.stream.AbstractPipeline.wrapAndCopyInto(Unknown Source)
        at java.util.stream.FindOps$FindOp.evaluateSequential(Unknown Source)
        at java.util.stream.AbstractPipeline.evaluate(Unknown Source)
        at java.util.stream.ReferencePipeline.findFirst(Unknown Source)
        at org.openqa.selenium.remote.ProtocolHandshake.createSession(ProtocolHandshake.java:128)
        at org.openqa.selenium.remote.ProtocolHandshake.createSession(ProtocolHandshake.java:74)
        at org.openqa.selenium.remote.HttpCommandExecutor.execute(HttpCommandExecutor.java:136)
        at org.openqa.selenium.remote.service.DriverCommandExecutor.execute(DriverCommandExecutor.java:83)
        at org.openqa.selenium.remote.RemoteWebDriver.execute(RemoteWebDriver.java:552)
        at org.openqa.selenium.remote.RemoteWebDriver.startSession(RemoteWebDriver.java:213)
        at org.openqa.selenium.remote.RemoteWebDriver.<init>(RemoteWebDriver.java:131)
        at org.openqa.selenium.firefox.FirefoxDriver.<init>(FirefoxDriver.java:162)
        at jp.vmi.selenium.webdriver.FirefoxDriverFactory.newInstance(FirefoxDriverFactory.java:69)
        at jp.vmi.selenium.webdriver.WebDriverManager$Builder.build(WebDriverManager.java:84)
        at jp.vmi.selenium.webdriver.WebDriverManager.get(WebDriverManager.java:276)
        at jp.vmi.selenium.selenese.Main.setupRunner(Main.java:153)
        at jp.vmi.selenium.selenese.Main.run(Main.java:96)
        at jp.vmi.selenium.selenese.Main.main(Main.java:294)
[2020-04-30 19:07:01.130 +09:00] [INFO] Exit code: 70 (FATAL)
```

i don't know what i am missing. help me to recify the error.

Comment: [INFO] No capabilities.
org.openqa.selenium.SessionNotCreatedException: Unable to find a matching set of capabilities

Comment: @Infern0 got solution i changed driver to remote and added remote-url